# I have multiple filenames with different versions . how to pick the highest numbered version from every filename

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redhat

I have multiple filenames with different versions . how to pick the highest numbered version from every filename.

```
ganglia-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-debuginfo-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-devel-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmetad-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-python-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-web-3.7.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-debuginfo-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-devel-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmetad-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-python-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-web-3.8.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm\BMS-CEI2_BC-ADAP-19.04.1111-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-ADAP-19.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-ADAP-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-19.04.1111-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-19.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
glusterfs-cli-3.12.13-1.el9.x86_64.rpm
glusterfs-cli-3.12.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
glusterfs-cli-3.13.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Output should be :

```
ganglia-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-debuginfo-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-devel-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmetad-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-python-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-web-3.8.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
glusterfs-cli-3.13.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-ADAP-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
```

i went through a method like taking prefixes and using `ls -v` command to get the versions ...
like

```
ganglia
ganglia-debuginfo
ganglia-dlevel
ganglia-web
.....
```

and used `ls -v prefix* | tail -n 1 ..`
i could get the prefect things but only for ganglia prefix i'm not able to get the perfect thing..please help me

I am able to get O/P

```
glusterfs-cli-3.13.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-ADAP-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
ganglia-debuginfo-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-devel-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmetad-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-python-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-web-3.8.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

I am not able to get this ganglia-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm in O/P

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -ltr *.rpm |awk '{print $9}' | sed '/^$/d' >> .ALLRPMNAMES.txt
# An associative array
declare -A names

# Iterate across the files, stripping version numbers and saving the name/prefix
for file in *.rpm
do
    name=${file%%-[0-9]*}    # Assume "-" and a non-zero digit marks the version
    ((names[$name]++))
done
echo " ${!names[@]}" >> RPMPREFIX.txt
sed -i 's/\s\+/\n/g' RPMPREFIX.txt
sed -i '/^$/d' RPMPREFIX.txt
while read line
do
ls -v $line* | tail -n 1 >> HighversionedRPMSALL.txt   
done < RPMPREFIX.txt
grep -Fxvf HighversionedRPMSALL.txt .ALLRPMNAMES.txt | grep -v 'k.sh' >> LowVersionedRPMS.txt
```

Comment: Welcome in SO. Please, post the code you already have and we will improve it. Don't ask us to code from scratch.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
ls -ltr *.rpm |awk '{print $9}' | sed '/^$/d' >> .ALLRPMNAMES.txt
# An associative array
declare -A names

# Iterate across the files, stripping version numbers and saving the name/prefix
for file in *.rpm
do
    name=${file%%-[0-9]*}    # Assume "-" and a non-zero digit marks the version
    ((names[$name]++))
done

Comment: echo " ${!names[@]}" >> RPMPREFIX.txt
sed -i 's/\s\+/\n/g' RPMPREFIX.txt
sed -i '/^$/d' RPMPREFIX.txt
while read line
do
ls -v $line* | tail -n 1 >> HighversionedRPMSALL.txt   
done < RPMPREFIX.txt
grep -Fxvf HighversionedRPMSALL.txt .ALLRPMNAMES.txt | grep -v 'k.sh' >> LowVersionedRPMS.txt

Comment: im not able to attach code ! so pasted in two comments

Comment: No, don't post code into comments but editing your question. Code is unreadable in the comments.

Comment: yes just added in question

Comment: Thank you. Look at my solution: the same in 4 lines of code.

Comment: If you want your code to be more robust, you can use `rpm` itself to tell you the package names and versions: `rpm -qp --queryformat '%{NAME} %{VERSION}\n' *rpm`. That way you can be sure that you have the package name and the version parts correct.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably already have figured out, a possible way to get the list of the package names is:

```
list_of_prefixes=$(ls -v *.rpm | sed 's/-[0-9].*$//' | uniq)
```

The assumption behind this is that a hyphen `-` in the filename followed by a digit indicates the beginning of the version string.

So, to get only the last version of each package, you could try:

```
for prefix in $list_of_prefixes; do 
  ls -rv $prefix-[0-9]* | head -n1
done
```

You will have noticed that, instead of listing the files in an ascending order and taking the last one with the command `tail`, I preferred to list the files in reverse order with the option `-r` for taking the first one with the command `head -n1`. I think this is faster.

**Demo:**
List of the files:

```
$ ls
BMS-CEI2_BC-19.04.1111-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-19.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-ADAP-19.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-ADAP-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
ganglia-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-debuginfo-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-debuginfo-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-devel-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-devel-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmetad-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmetad-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-python-3.7.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-python-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-web-3.7.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-web-3.8.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
glusterfs-cli-3.12.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
glusterfs-cli-3.12.13-1.el9.x86_64.rpm
glusterfs-cli-3.13.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

List of the packages:

```
$ listofprefixes=$(ls -v | sed 's/-[0-9].*$//' | uniq)
$ echo "$listofprefixes"
BMS-CEI2_BC
BMS-CEI2_BC-ADAP
ganglia
ganglia-debuginfo
ganglia-devel
ganglia-gmetad
ganglia-gmond
ganglia-gmond-python
ganglia-web
glusterfs-cli
```

List of last version of each package:

```
$ for p in $listofprefixes ; do ls -rv $p-[0-9]* | head -n1 ; done
BMS-CEI2_BC-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
BMS-CEI2_BC-ADAP-20.04.1112-4_1.noarch.rpm
ganglia-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-debuginfo-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-devel-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmetad-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-gmond-python-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
ganglia-web-3.8.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
glusterfs-cli-3.13.13-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

The entry `ganglia-3.8.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm` is present.

Comment: super thanks ... i went very long .i will modify mine